# In wordpress theme How can i add custom search

Tags: wordpress

How create custom search form in WordPress . i want to create form there three drop-down boxes . Select from this boxes values and then press search button to search from database.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form you can create a filename called 'searchform.php' in your theme with your custom search form. More details in the link above.